A Natural Probability Distribution on the Infinite Symmetric Group
Is there a "natural" probability distribution on the set of bijections from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself? Preferably, I would want a distribution which arises from some combinatorial procedure. For example, the set of shuffles of a partition $(A,B)$ of $\mathbb{N}$ can be generated by the string of binary choices: is the next number in $A$ or $B?$ This satisfies the conditions of the central limit theorem, so we can model the arising distribution as a Gaussian, namely the binomial distribution. Unfortunately, in the case of a general bijection, there is no such obvious generating procedure, as we cannot even specify domain of choice for a particular output. Is there some way around this? Perhaps some asymptotic justification that bijections which have outputs consistently far from inputs are less probable?

Depending on what properties you want of the probability distribution/measure, the following is a negative answer. The symmetric group $G = \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ on a set $X$ contains copies of any group $F$ of cardinality at most $X$: embed $F$ inside $X$ as a set and consider $F$ acting on itself by left multiplication, which embeds $F$ inside $\operatorname{Sym}(F) \subset \operatorname{Sym}(X) = G$. In particular if $X$ is infinite then $G$ contains non-abelian free groups and hence is not amenable, ie it does not have a left-invariant probability measure.
